# Compare every last two records inside ng repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Below are the records :

```
$scope.myArray = 
  [
    {
      "id": 100,
      "child": [
        {
          "id": 77,
          "part": 33,
          "name" : 16
          "subName": 16.1,
        },
        {
          "id": 76,
          "part": 30,
          "name" : 14,
          "subName": 14.3,
        },
       {
        "id": 75,
        "part": 29,
        "name" : 12,
        "subName": 12.1,
       }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

Now in above records,16.1 belongs to part = 33 and 14.3 belongs to part = 30 so as both the Subname belongs to different parts so I would like to display name 16 and 14.

So expected output for above records are like below which I am getting:

```
16
14
12
```

Problem comes when i have below records :

```
$scope.myArray = 
  [
    {
      "id": 100,
      "child": [
        {
          "id": 76,
          "part": 30,
          "name" : 14,
          "subName": 14.3,
        },
        {
          "id": 71,
          "part": 30,
          "name" : 14,
          "subName": 14.2,
        },
        {
          "id": 70,
          "part": 30,
          "name" : 14,
          "subName": 14.1,
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

Here child contains all subname for same part ie 30 so now I want to display Subname.So expected output in this case will be Subname like below :

```
14.3
14.2
14.1
```

Records will be compare from 0 - 1,1 - 2, 2 - 3 but here I am not getting how to compare records if child array contains more than two records.

**Note:** I will not have duplicate part in child array if any of the two records contains different part. For example, I will not have Subname like 16.1,14.3,14.2 as because here I have 16.1 which belongs to different part. But if 16.1 is not there then I can have 14.3,14.2 which are of same part.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
        app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {
          $scope.myArray = 
  [
    {
      "id": 100,
      "child": [
        {
          "id": 77,
          "part": 33,
          "name" : 16,
          "subName": 16.1,
        },
        {
          "id": 76,
          "part": 30,
          "name" : 14,
          "subName": 14.3,
        },
        {
          "id": 75,
          "part": 29,
          "name" : 12,
          "subName": 12.1,
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
        });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-repeat="item in myArray[0].child">
       {{ item.name }} 
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: After reading your request for the third time, I have no Idea what you're talking about. `in above records,16.1 belongs to part = 33 and 14.3 belongs to part = 30` how do they belong to? what does that mean? 16.1 and 33 are values on the same object. `So expected output for above records are like below which i am getting: 16 14 12` where does the 12 come from? `Records will be compare from 0 - 1,1 - 2, 2 - 3` how compare? You don't compare anything in your whole question. Long story short, we're not in your head. Please explain it like you're talking to somebody that has never seen your code.

Comment: @Thomas:There is 1 to many relationship between part and subName.Like 1 part can have many subNames.For eg.Part 30 have 3 subnames
i.e 14.3,14.2 and 14.1.Part 33 have only 1 Subname i.e 16.1.I have updated my question to include 12 in my input.I hope now it is making sense to you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see below controller code. I tried to implement what you want.

```
$scope.myArray = [ {
        "id" : 100,
        "child" : [ {
            "id" : 76,
            "part" : 30,
            "name" : 14,
            "subName" : 14.3,
        }, {
            "id" : 71,
            "part" : 30,
            "name" : 14,
            "subName" : 14.2,
        }, {
            "id" : 70,
            "part" : 30,
            "name" : 14,
            "subName" : 14.1,
        } ]
    }, {
        "id" : 101,
        "child" : [ {
            "id" : 77,
            "part" : 33,
            "name" : 16,
            "subName" : 16.1,
        }, {
            "id" : 76,
            "part" : 30,
            "name" : 14,
            "subName" : 14.3,
        }, {
            "id" : 75,
            "part" : 29,
            "name" : 12,
            "subName" : 12.1,
        } ]
    } ]
```

HTML code:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in myArray">
            ============<br />
            <div ng-repeat="item1 in item.child">
                <span>{{(item1.part==item.child[$index+1].part ||
                    ($index==item.child.length-1 &&
                    item1.part==item.child[$index-1].part))?item1.subName:item1.name}}</span>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Here I am checking that, if current item and next item's part are same or not and if it is last item then current item and previous item's part are same or not and based on that I am displaying `subName` or `name`. I hope this solution will work for you.

Updated:

```js
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.myArray = [{
            "id": 100,
            "child": [{
                "id": 76,
                "part": 30,
                "name": 14,
                "subName": 14.3,
            }, {
                "id": 71,
                "part": 30,
                "name": 14,
                "subName": 14.2,
            }, {
                "id": 70,
                "part": 30,
                "name": 14,
                "subName": 14.1,
            }]
        }, {
            "id": 101,
            "child": [{
                "id": 77,
                "part": 33,
                "name": 16,
                "subName": 16.1,
            }, {
                "id": 76,
                "part": 30,
                "name": 14,
                "subName": 14.3,
            }, {
                "id": 75,
                "part": 29,
                "name": 12,
                "subName": 12.1,
            }]
        }]
    });
```

```html
<html ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
   <head>
      <title></title>
      <meta charset="utf-8" />
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div ng-repeat="item in myArray">
         ============<br />
         <div ng-repeat="item1 in item.child">
            <span>{{(item1.part==item.child[$index+1].part ||
            ($index==item.child.length-1 &&
            item1.part==item.child[$index-1].part))?item1.subName:item1.name}}</span>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Upvoted for your kind efforts towards helping me.Can you create a runnable code like the way i have created so that i can run it?

Comment: Hi, I have added runnable code. Please mark it as answer if it does what you want.